# Check specific blok Heading if parent checkbox is selected all child checkbox is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is 3 div with child type checkbox
[image]

when click on one 1st div only 1st div child check box checked other block same as it nothing on it .

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre], and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: (Right now, I can't even tell if what you wrote it supposed to be the description of current, faulty behavior, or the actual result you want to achieve.)

Answer (score 0):

I seem to understand what you want so scary

```js
$(".sub-item").on("click", function() {
  $(this).parent(".submenu").prev(".title").css("color", "red")
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <span class="title">Title</span>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li class="sub-item">subtitle</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Seems roughly the right idea, except OP is using multiple checkboxes.  OPs request appears to be: click on parent, child items are selected.   From the screenshot it's clearly a "select all in this group" mechanism - how much OP want's that to work beyond click parent->select all is debatable - ie do they want that if you uncheck a child it unchecks parent - what if you check all children, should it check parent?   I read *1st div only 1st div child check box checked* as "check parent, check all children"

Comment: an unclear question. it would be easier to code if he edited the question